# boost thread, test if thread is ready to join

Tags: c++, boost, join, multithreading

I would like to know if there is a way to test whenever thread finished execution and is waiting for joining.  My guess was the use time_join.
is there explicit way to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API for that in `boost::thread`. I think the reason is that a thread can be *detached* and made not-[`joinable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.joinable). Your best recourse is probably a wrapper and a flag.

Answer (score 1):

timed_join with a duration of 0 can be seen as a try_join, so yes you can test if a thread has been finish. I think that there is already a feature request to add this try_join function to Boost.Thread.